# How to rbind data.frames with different header inside a lapply loop?

Tags: r, csv

I'm creating a big `data.frame` out of many smaller `data.frames` stored in csv format. To make the process time efficient (of which I'm very needy), I'm importing my files with a `lapply`:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(file_list,read.csv))
```

One of these `data.frames` has an extra row with the names for the columns, which create a discrepancy when binding everything together.

```
read.csv(df1.csv,sep=";",header=TRUE)
  col1 col2
1  1    2

read.csv("df2.csv",sep=";",header=FALSE)
   V1 V2
1  3  4

read.csv("df3.csv",sep=";",header=FALSE)
   V1 V2
1  5  6

do.call(rbind,lapply(c("df1.csv","df2.csv","df3.csv"),read.csv))
```

> Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
>         names do not match previous names

Later, I tried to get rid of of the colnames with a custom.read.csv to no avail:

```
custom_read.csv <- function(r) {
  if (grepl("df1.csv",r)) {
    data <- read.csv(r,sep=";",header=TRUE)
     names(data) <- NULL
    data
  } else {
    data <- read.csv(r,sep=";",header=FALSE)
    data
  }
}

do.call(rbind,lapply(c("df1.csv","df2.csv","df3.csv"),custom_read.csv))
```

> Error in pi[[j]] : subscript out of bounds

If I exclude the `data.frame` with the header, I get my desired output:

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(c("df2.csv","df3.csv"),custom_read.csv))
    V1  V2
 1   3   4
 2   5   6
```

How can I get rbind to combine data.frames with and without colnames on the fly? In the worst case, how can I remove completely the name attributes of the data frame with header?

Comment: The helper function in data.table ignores names after the first data.frame by default: `data.table::rbindlist(list(data.frame(a = 1), data.frame(V1 = 1)))`

Comment: look at `dplyr`'s `rbind.fill`

Comment: Maybe just give the columns names in both `if/else` blocks.

Comment: @emilliman5 dplyr::rbind.fill seems to no longer be in the package. Strangely, I can't get bind_rows to do it either, though. Oh ok, it's in plyr, not dplyr.

Comment: @Frank, good catch. Though, it look looks like it has been moved to `bind_rows` in `dplyr`